# Sending a txt file from iOS Device to a Rails App

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

Currently, my iOS app creates a file (for simplicity sakes, let's say it is a textfile). I want to be able to send it to my Rails app via a HTTP POST request.

Currently, I convert the file into NSData, create a request (NSMutableURLRequest) with the url to a POST route. I then use NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest to attempt to send the file over.

For my Rails side, I created a home route with a button that uploads the file and submits it via the POST Route. This works locally (ie if I upload file from my computer, it goes through).

However, I get back a 503 error which means that the Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.

Does this mean that:
a. My implementation of the sender is incorrect
b. My implementation of the receiver is incorrect
c. Something else might be wrong

**UPDATE**

Following the instructions in the comment, I have my log as follows:

```
Process running mem=1222M(238.7%)
2015-08-04T19:44:04.014099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-08-04T19:44:12.737956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/update" host=serverforperfomance.herokuapp.com request_id=0d24dfb1-4366-416c-b7c4-57c48659a275 fwd="66.211.109.190" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=44140ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I would still like to know whether my implementation is correct, or if it is just heroku having too little memory for what I need it to do.

Comment: You should give us relevant lines from your `log/production.log` (if you run your Rails server in production environment) or `log/development.log`. Just write in terminal `tail -f log/production.log` on your server, then start the request from your iOS device, and then copy-paste the lines you see.

Comment: Oh interesting.

Process running mem=1222M(238.7%)
2015-08-04T19:44:04.014099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-08-04T19:44:12.737956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/update" host=serverforperfomance.herokuapp.com request_id=0d24dfb1-4366-416c-b7c4-57c48659a275 fwd="66.211.109.190" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=44140ms status=503 bytes=0

Ok, well... is the file I'm sending too big? Or is the act of transferring the file too memory intensive? Is there a way I can do this while not paying for more memory?

Comment: Update your question with information you discovered. I will write up my advice as an answer.

Comment: What is the size of the file beigg uploaded?

Comment: I was sending 100Mb. Though I get 422 error when I drop it to 100b. That is probably because I haven't really finished the uploader...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered, problem is due to memory limit.

I suggest using direct uploads to S3 – so that file will bypass your sever.

You can use [Carrierwave Direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) gem for that. Read the documentation for solution – it's pretty straight forward. You will need to add query parameters which you see as web form parameters here

```
%form{:action => @uploader.direct_fog_url, :method => "post", :enctype => "multipart/form-data"}
  %input{:name => "utf8", :type => "hidden"}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "key", :value => @uploader.key}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "AWSAccessKeyId", :value => @uploader.aws_access_key_id}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "acl", :value => @uploader.acl}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "success_action_redirect", :value => @uploader.success_action_redirect}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "policy", :value => @uploader.policy}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "signature", :value => @uploader.signature}
  %input{:name => "file", :type => "file"}
  %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Upload to S3"}
```

as your request parameters in your iOS code.

Large file uploads tends to capture a lot of CPU/memory resources, so best option is to not use Heroku for them (i.e. using direct-to-S3 uploads as I suggested, or have separate non-heroku server to handles uploads and/or post-processing), because any additional resources are rather limited/expensive for you.

**UPD**. Good post on optimizing Heroku setup: [How to get More Bang for your Heroku Buck While Making Your Rails Site Super Snappy [Redux]](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/how-to-get-more-bang-for-your-heroku-buck-while-making-your-rails-site-super-snappy-redux/).

Comment: Hmmm, but say I do want my own site to have access to file (say to display the contents of the textfile on the site). 

Also does direct to S3 cause a slower transfer time than sending to my server?

Comment: Direct to S3 will be most likely faster (S3 servers don't have deliberate CPU/broadband/etc. limits), but will depend on network conditions (path between user and your server and S3). File uploads with limited Heroku account is really a painful thing. Also added link to post on optimizing your Heroku server. But, generally, if you don't have resources you don't have them. I would personally consider moving to some VPS (digital ocean, slicehost, etc.) which will be cheaper, though will require some work to setup.

Comment: Oh that's good then.

But my website won't be able to access said file, but have to pull it from S3 then?

Or in other words, there is no better solution?

Comment: Yeah, my opinion is that there's no better solution. You can pull that file back from S3, but chances are, your web dyno will die trying that (no difference from getting the file from client). Best case scenario would be to design your app in a way that would allow user *himself* to pull file back from S3, and render in appropriate place.